# How to exclude double dot(..) and single dot(.) in find-file using `helm`?

Tags: helm

I am using `helm` for find files. I have followed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43632653/2402577

```
(helm-mode 1)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-f"  'helm-find-files)

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-omit-mode)
(setq dired-omit-files
      (rx (or (seq bol (? ".") "#")
              (seq bol "." eol)
              (seq bol ".." eol)
              )))
```

---

During the search `.` and `..` always shows up on the top of the search.

```
Find files or url: /home/user/folder/
Find Files (C-l: Go up one level)
/home/user/folder/.
/home/user/folder/..
...
```

**[Q]** Is it possible to not show them? or show them/hidden files on the bottom of the search?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It seems to `helm-find-files`, `.` and `..` are considered entries of a directory which are always available. And they not always show up, when you filter the entries by entering something, they will disappear.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to show hidden files bottom of the search rather than showning them on the top?